# Настройка DNS в Docker

Tags: docker, dns

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с DNS сервером не разу не настраивал и как правильно это делать не очень понимаю. Единственный раз когда у меня DNS заработал это когда я установил Hestia Control Panel. Но настройка автоматом конечно хорошо но всё же хочется разобраться как работает и как надо правильно настраивать. В данный момент использую Docker и тут у меня вообще полный ступор как связать DNS сервер с Docker что бы домены можно было привязать по NS-записям и если к примеру я буду добавлять или удалять какой то домен то это можно было сделать через консоль.

Одолжив бубен у шамана что то получилось сделать а именно сделал следующее:

(Для примера буду использовать домен lab-net.lan)

1. Создал сеть

   docker network create lan-lab-net --subnet 172.24.0.0/16
2. Создал файлы с таким содержимым:

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y bind9

COPY named.conf.options /etc/bind/
COPY named.conf.local /etc/bind/
COPY db.lab-net.lan /etc/bind/zones/

CMD ["/usr/sbin/named", "-g", "-c", "/etc/bind/named.conf", "-u", "bind"]

EXPOSE 53/tcp
EXPOSE 53/udp
EXPOSE 953/tcp
```

***named.conf.options***

```
options {    
directory "/var/cache/bind";    
recursion yes;    
listen-on { any; };    
forwarders {            
8.8.8.8;            
8.8.4.4;    
};};
```

***named.conf.local***

```
zone "lab-net.lan" {    
type master;    
file "/etc/bind/zones/db.lab-net.lan";
};
```

***db.lab-net.lan***

```
$TTL    1d ; 
;default expiration time (in seconds) of all RRs without their own TTL value
@       IN      SOA   ns1.lab-net.lan. root.lab-net.lan.  (
        3      ; Serial
        1d     ; Refresh
        1h     ; Retry
        1w     ; Expire
        1h ); Negative Cache TTL;

;name servers - NS records
@         IN      NS      ns1.lab-net.lan.; 
    
;name servers - A records
ns1.lab-net.lan.          IN      A      172.24.0.2 
lab-net.lan.        IN      A      172.24.0.3
```

3. Создал контейнер для DNS и присвоил ему IP 172.24.0.2

   docker run -d -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp -p 127.0.0.1:953:953/tcp --rm --name=dns-master --net=lan-lab-net --ip=172.24.0.2 b9-serv:b9
4. Создал тестовый контейнер и присвоил ему IP 172.24.0.3

   docker run -d --rm --name=test-conteiner --net=lan-lab-net --ip=172.24.0.3 --dns=172.24.0.2 test1:t1

После всех манипуляций и незначительных исправлений при проверке через nslookup вроде что то заработало

```
user@user:~# nslookup
> server 172.24.0.2
Default server: 172.24.0.2
Address: 172.24.0.2#53
> lab-net.lan
Server:         172.24.0.2
Address:        172.24.0.2#53

Name:   lab-net.lan
Address: 172.24.0.3
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне теперь по домену lab-net.lan зайти на сайт из интернета что нужно ещё настроить?

Comment: Но это же ваш локальный DNS, из интернета только если вы обратитесь к вашему серверу по ip он сможет разрезолвить вам это имя в ip. Если я правильно понял. Просто так отдать имя во внешние dns сервера кому угодно нельзя же, иначе это бардак будет. Максимум что вы можете - настроить ваши какие-то внутренние компьютеры так, чтобы они этот ваш dns server использовали и тогда на этих компьютерах можно будет это имя резолвить в ip.

Comment: Ну когда я на удаленном компе делаю nslookup моего домена то вижу IP адрес контейнера. Мне теперь бы понять как сайт вывести в инет.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы опубликовать сайт в интернете, вам нужно 5 вещей:

1. домен, приобретенный у регистратора
2. статический внешний IP адрес у той машины, на которой крутятся ваш докер либо nginx proxy который распределяет запросы между вашими докерами
3. A-запись у регистратора о том, что ваш домен соответствует вашему внешнему статическому IP
4. Проброс портов внутрь (80,443 и т.д.) на маршрутизаторе, через который ваша машина выходит в инет
5. Правила iptables/ufw на машине о том, что с внешнего IP можно подключаться по этим портам

Когда вы регистрируете домен у регистратора (nic.ru, reg.ru и т.д.) он попадает в глобальную публичную таблицу DNS записей. И только после этого любой ПК в интернете сможет понять, что вашему домену соответствует ваш внешний статический ip и пойти по нему.

`.lan` это ваш локальный домен, который виден только из вашей локальной сети и его никак нельзя использовать снаружи.

Comment: У меня есть свой домен для этого домена прописаны ns записи у регистратора. Вот как мне контейнер вывести из локалки в большой мир?

Comment: Да забыл добавить домен который у меня указан .lan использовался как пример и не более того

Comment: @Mister_X тогда смотрите пункты 4 и 5 - проверяйте NAT и фаервол. Когда браузер обращается на сайт, он стучит в 80 порт, это значит он должен быть проброшен с маршрутизатора на локальный IP докер-контейнера

Comment: так у меня есть внешний IP (пускай внешний мой IP будет 1.1.1.1) который приходит на роутер и с роутера по статике приходит на сервак ( локальный IP от роутера до сервака пускай будет 192.168.0.2) и для контейнера на котором крутится сайт я назначил IP 172.24.0.3 ... как вывести сайт не очень понимаю ... если поднять всё на серваке без docker то сайт будет работать без проблем ... не когда до этого не настраивал DNS и сети как то потребностей не нужны были.

Comment: с последнего моего ответа я сидел искал информацию про docker и вот только сейчас понял что мне не давал покоя Ваш ответ и главное мне было не очень понятно причем тут порты перечитав еще раз ответ решил не много так сказать обновить свой вопрос и возможно Вы знаете на него ответ или кто то сможет на него мне ответить.

Comment: Вопрос вот какой возможно ли зайти в контейнер docker по ip адресу данного контейнера не используя порты из внешней локальной сети 
Моя внешняя сеть 192.168.1.0/24 ... сеть в docker 172.24.0.0/16 ... ip контейнера по которому я хочу зайти из внешней сети 172.24.0.2

Да сразу скажу что локальную сеть 172.24.0.0/16 в роуторе прописал с маской 255.255.255.0 и шлюз указал локальный ip адрес моего сервера 192.168.1.2